# Updating SQL Table Data In Android Applcation

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update my local android app database data , I used the update query:

```
public void addQTY(String changedQTY, String changedPNAme) {
    String addQuery = "UPDATE" + SQLITE_TABLE + 
            "SET" + qty + "='" + changedQTY + "'" +
            "WHERE" + PRODUCT_NAME + "='" + changedPNAme + "';";
    mDb.execSQL(addQuery);
}
```

the app is crashing whenever I use this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give space after `WHERE` and `UPDATE` cause

```
String addQuery = "UPDATE " + SQLITE_TABLE + 
        " SET "+ qty+"='"+ changedQTY +"'" +
        " WHERE " +PRODUCT_NAME + "='" + changedPNAme + "';
```

### OR

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("qty", changedQTY);
mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE , values, PRODUCT_NAME + "='" + changedPNAme + "'", null);
```