# How to update all attributes of a row except Unique Constraint attribute in Android SQLITE?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert-update, unique-constraint

I am working on an android app. In database I have a column that applied Unique Constraint.
CreateEntry Method Working Perfectly.

Now In Create Entry Method I want to update all attributes except Unique Attribute.

My Current Code Goes Here:

### Creating Table

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" + KEY_ROWID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NOTE
        + " TEXT NULL, " + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);");
}
```

### CreateEntry Method In Database Class

```
public long createEntry(String number, String note) throws SQLException {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
    cv.put(KEY_NOTE, note);

    return callBlockerDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, cv);
}
```

as KEY_NUMBER is unique attribute.

First attempt:  i passed "123" as number and "abc" as note to CreateEntry Method.

2nd Attempt: I passed "123" as number and "xyz" as note.

In second attempt I want to Update "xyz" as note a in specified row.

Please help me to update CreateEntry Method for achieving mentioned goal ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839784/updating-sql-table-data-in-android-applcation/29839794#29839794](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839784/updating-sql-table-data-in-android-applcation/29839794#29839794)

Comment: You can update the first row's note value using db.update()

Answer (score 1):

As you specified the KEY_NUMBER to unique it will not accept duplicate value '123'

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I want to update "xyz" in same row. and 123 should remain as same?

Comment: then you can use 

try{
 callBlockerDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, cv);
}catch(Exception e)
{
 callBlockerDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, cv);
}